# Wine unhandled stack overflow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine, ubuntu-16.04

I can't start wine, any version on my Ubuntu 16.04. It's not that I can't launch a *specific* program with wine, it's that I **cannot launch wine at all**. Every wine launch crashes by giving me this error :

```
wine: Unhandled stack overflow at address 0xXXXXX (thread XXXX), starting debugger...
err :seh:setup_exception_record stack overflow 1200 bytes in thread 0011 eip 7bc62f8d esp 00240e80 stack 0x240000-0x241000-0x3400000
```

The only working program is winetricks, and I can't use it to launch winecfg or anything else : getting this error every time.

I tried with Wine2.0, wine1.8, 1.6, tried deleting the .wine folder or the wine prefix but once it's done, I cannot even wineboot to recreate it.

What can I do to fix this ?

Comment: I had the same error being printed; probably not the exact same issue, but simply `apt update`'ing `wine` did the trick. I was using 2.0.2 instead of 3.0.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it.
In fact, it was not only Wine, but a lot of programs (LeafPad, LxAppearance, and some other stuff) that did cause a segmentation fault and crash.

So I used `strace` to investigate the error and I found that these applications, upon crashing, did try to load cursor icon files that did **not exist**.

And while I did install some cursor themes something like a week ago (Breeze theme, to replace Adwaita Theme), it did not work back in the days and I just stopped caring about it (as I'm using i3 as a window manager and changing the general graphic behavior of i3 is a bit complicated).

Obviously, the cursor change was taken in account only after the next login after the switch. And once the "glitched" cursor theme loaded, instead of falling back into the default X11 cursor theme (or Adwaita) when a specified icon could not be found, it was creating some "out of memory bounds" shit.

Problem fixed by uninstalling then installing again, properly, the Breeze theme (and I also installed a lot of them). Installing themes on this is system is done this way :

- Copying all themes in separate folders, in ~/.icons/
- Removing all the symbolic links in theses themes folders using `find -type l -delete` among them
- Create a symbolic link for each of your themes folders so they also appear in /usr/share/icons the same way they do in ~/.icons
- Switching theme with lxappearance (if you didn't delete the symbolic links previously, by here you'll get the segmentation fault stuff in almost every program). At this point, it will be all glitched out cursors because links are missing.
- Restore all the symbolic links you've deleted in step 2, by extracting them again from the theme archive for exemple.

Then reboot. Once the theme is successfully loaded and understood by LxAppearance, the segmentation fault errors never occur again.

Also you may notice that some themes (AdWaita for example) support to be switched on with LXA despite the fact that they've got symbolic links inside them, while some others (like Breeze and its variants) do not and need you to repeat theses operations every time.

Ah, Linux and the graphical interfaces. Love to get general system failures caused by a missing cursor icon file.